# Symfony2 - Form Type Value to Another Field

Tags: php, forms, symfony

How to get the value of the `field and move` to the `same form`.

**example:**

A `field` with the choice - `Man and Woman`

`Another field` if selected `man show - car` or if the field above is selected `woman - handbag`

I know that you can use `javascript`, but would like to learn to do `directly from symfony`.

Comment: please show the code

Comment: See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html and http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: Please format your question accordingly to standards and also add the code you wish to modify or to achieve your goal with.